# Redis maxmemory-policy expires keys inside HashSets?

Tags: redis

Can someone clarify if `maxmemory-policy` applies to **HashSets**? 
Say, for example, I have a key named `REGION`, under that I have multiple key-value data:

```
1) northamerica 12345
2) southafrica 1234
3) southeastasia 2311
```

`southafrica` is seldom accessed. Will it be evicted if my policy is `allkeys-lru`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis supports eviction only on **KEY** level. It does not support eviction on inner element(s) of any key.

So, `southafrica` would be evicted if and only if `REGION` HashSet is evicted. As long as `REGION` is there, `southafrica` won't be removed (unless you remove it by yourself).

Answer (score 0):

LRU is Least Recently Used, and it refers to the key itself and not to the different elements in it. In your case `REGION`.

When you choose an eviction policy from the `allkey-*` family you must be prepared to loose any data stored in your Redis.

If there are keys you are not willing to lose, make sure your eviction policy can not evict them under any circumstance.